# Changing button breaks the CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website that has been partially constructed.

I came across this code which displays a button without the href

```
<div class="practices__btn"><button>Learn More</button></div>
```

I've tried to fix it with the following code but find that it breaks the CSS.

```
<button class="practices__btn"><a href="#">Learn More</a></button>
```

Here is the CSS code.

```
.practices__card h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.practices__card p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.practices__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.practices__card button {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #131313;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

This is the code that the button should fit into

```
<div class="practices" id="practices">
      <h1>Our Areas of Practice</h1>
      <div class="practices__wrapper">
        <div class="practices__card">
          <h2>test</h2>
          <p>
            "For some reason"
          </p>
          <button class="practices__btn"><a href="#">Learn More</a></button>
        </div>
```

I appreciate the help. I can't find the problem yet it seems simple.

Comment: I advise you to avoid saying things like "it's broken" or "doesn't work" because it really makes it hard to understand what you mean. Btw, I suppose the problem is that the anchor (`<a>`) replaces the style with the browser default, so just add `color: parent; text-decoration: none` to the `a` selector

Comment: Also, having an anchor within a button isn't a best practice. Remember that HTML is *also* semantic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using an anchor tag (`<a>`) on a button is the best practice. My advice is to make it a `form` instead, then add an `action` to it.

```css
.practices__card h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.practices__card p {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 24px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.practices__btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.practices__card button {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #131313;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="practices" id="practices">
  <h1>Our Areas of Practice</h1>
  <div class="practices__wrapper">
    <div class="practices__card">
      <h2>test</h2>
      <p>
      "For some reason"
      </p>
      <div class="practices__btn">
        <form action="https://example.com">
          <button type="submit" class="practices__btn">Learn More</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```